# How to make biber read fields with value "0"?

Tags: biblatex, biber

Is there a way to force biber to read fields with value "0"? (background: I use a user-defined field citeable as boolean and it would be convenient to distinguish between the cases undefined, "0" and "1". Currently undefined and "0" are the same).

Small example using the field note:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a2016,
  author        = {Author, A.},
  note          = {0},
  journal       = {Journal},
  title         = {Title1},
  year          = {2016}
}
@article{b2016,
  author        = {Author, B.},
  journal       = {Journal},
  title         = {Title2},
  year          = {2016}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Make a bug report. https://github.com/plk/biber/issues. `note` is a normal text field and imho it shouldn't loose a zero.

Comment: Fixed in biber 2.7, currently in development folder on Sourceforge.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report, solved with new version

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in biber and is fixed in version 2.7 on SourceForge.